# Does an if statement in Ruby call a particular object method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Maybe I am not quite understanding something fundamental, but I was wondering if some particular method of an object is called when evaluating it for an `if` statement?

So, in the below...

```
my_object = MyObject.new

if !my_object
  puts 'Hello, world!'
end

class MyObject
  def ___
    return false
  end
end
```

...is there some method `___` that I could define within the object that would called by `if`, such that I can determine the result of the conditional? (in the above, the output would be 'Hello, world!')

Or is there some other way I can, from the definition of `MyObject`, have control over how it will be evaluated in an `if` statement?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is not possible but you should prefer alternative to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` should evaulate to true if the variable is anything other than `nil` or `false` (and will error if the variable isn't defined). I'm not sure that there's a way to override an object that's defined to return a nil or false (that isn't confusing to most Ruby programmers) but I'd be interested to hear from others.

What you can do is add a method to return a `nil` or `false` value and use that instead:

```
class MyObject
  def foo?
    false
  end
end

obj = MyObject.new

if obj.foo?
  puts "true"
else
  puts "false"
end
```

Update: You can override the `new` method to return a boolean, rather than the object.

```
class MyObject
  attr_reader :var

  def initialize(*args)
    args.each do |a|
      puts a
    end
  end

  def self.new(*args, &block)
    super
    false
  end
end

my_object = MyObject.new(:a, :b)

if !my_object
  puts 'Hello, world!'
end


my_object = MyObject.new

if !my_object
  puts 'Hello, world!'
end
```

There might be any number of side effects with that, since you've basically converted the instance of the object to a boolean. It might be an interesting exploration though, but I'd probably stick with changing my assignment or doing a `defined?`, `is_a?`, `nil?` check or othewise.

Comment: Thanks, yes that should work. I just wondered if there might be a neater trick where we redefine how Ruby interprets the truth-value of MyObject, so that `obj` does actually == `nil` or `false` or `true`. Sounds like probably not!

Comment: You can check things like `is_a?(MyObject)`, `defined?(obj)`, etc. in addition to using the comparable mixin to test two things. You can also change your assignment earlier as `MyObject.new.results` (or something that would return nil or false). You could create a module/class with a method `def self.new` and override that to return false/nil. There might be a way to override `initialize`, maybe on the singleton class as well...There's probably a way I just can't think of a use case where it would be safe for anything other than an excerise in doing it to do it.

Comment: One side effect of the "return a boolean from `new`" chicanery is that `my_object.var` no longer works because `my_object` isn't an instance of `MyObject`. And since you don't have a reference to your `MyObject`, it effectively doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

> is there some method `___` that I could define within the object that would called by `if`, such that I can determine the result of the conditional?

No, unfortunately not. This is one of the cases where Ruby is unfortunately not object-oriented.

There are only two falsy objects in Ruby: `false` (obviously) and `nil`. Everything else is truthy, including objects that are considered falsy in some other languages, e.g. the integer `0`, the float `0.0`, the empty string `''`, the empty array `[]`, and the empty hash `{}`.

One of the fundamental pillars of object-orientation is that objects can simulate each other. In fact, some people argue that this is *the* defining feature of object-orientation. Yet, there is no way to simulate `false` or `nil` in Ruby.

> (in the above, the output would be 'Hello, world!')

In this particular case, you could achieve that by overriding `!`, but that would be cheating since it does not affect the truth value of the object itself:

```
class MyObject
  def !
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, a good explanation of why this isn't possible. Sadly the 'Hello, world' example was just an example so overriding `!` won't work for me. Also: I didn't think it was possible to override `!`?